# Javascript, игра крестики-нолики

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Пишу игру крестики-нолики с помощью таблицы, размеры зависят от вводимого значения. После каждого хода пользователя компьютер делает свой ход. Чтобы выявить победившего использую приведенную функцию.

Проблема в том, что функция работает некорректно. Всегда выдает "победа", когда ставишь крестик в последней ячейке. А должна, как следует из правил игры, выдавать "победа" только при наличии заполненной полностью строки, колонки или диагоналей.

```js
 function proverka() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  var flag;
  var tdQuan = 3;
  for (var k = 0; k < tdQuan; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tdQuan; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < tdQuan; j++) {

        if (table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML == table.rows[k].cells[j].innerHTML && table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML == "X" ||
          table.rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML == table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML && table.rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML == "X" ||
          table.rows[j].cells[j].innerHTML == "X") {
          flag = true;
        } else {
          flag = false;
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  
    if (flag === true) {
      alert("победа ");
    }

  }
}

 var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
 for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(this.innerHTML !== 'X'){
    this.innerHTML = 'X';
   } else {
    this.innerHTML = '';
   }
   proverka();
  })
 }
```

```css
td{
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли сказать решаемую задачу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov внизу ведь написано

Comment: Видимо, я слепой - ничего не вижу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ,
чтобы  выявить победившего написал такую функцию.
 Эта функция сравнивает только последнюю ячейку с - X.

Почему это так, и как на самом деле надо писать такую функцию

Comment: Так а что функция должна делать-то? Может, это правильное поведение, мы же не знаем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov пологаю Вы знакомы с игрой "иксик нолик", если не знакомы - там побеждает тот,  кто первым заполнит одну строку (по вертикально, по горизонтально или по диагонали)

Comment: С игрой я знаком, но я по-прежнему не понимаю что должна делать ваша функция.

Comment: @PavelMayorov функция должна сравнивать innerHTML ячеек по вертикали и по горизонтали

Comment: Ну, она их и сравнивает, кажется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет ,,, смотрите ,, он срабатывает только тогда , когда я кликаю   по последним ячейкам , даже если вся строка пуста , alert("победа "); срабатывает

Comment: Уберите alert из функции - она же должна сравнивать, а не сообщение выводить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я с помощью алерт  тестирую правильно ли работает функция , вместо него потом поставлю return true  ,,, но щяс она не корректно работает

Comment: @PavelMayorov можете сами убедиться (формат html)
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/MnXs/1FF2UKknt

Comment: Как вы поняли, что она некорректно работает? Вы же сами писали - она должна сравнивать. Она сравнивает? Сравнивает! Что еще-то надо?

Comment: @PavelMayorov , смотрите , даже при первом клике (когда все ячейки свободны ) если кликать по последним ячейкам линий , это функция даст значение true ,,, а мне так не надо , мне надо чтоб все элементы которые находятся в одной строке сравнивало с соседнями элементами той же строки, и только после этого когда всё innerHTML совпадают вернуло true

Comment: мне кажется я упустил какую то маленькую деталь , и за этого не получается у меня

Comment: @Тигран - Я уже отвечал Вам на такой вопрос - в момент когда `flag = true;`, Вам нужно выйти из циклов и из функции.

Comment: @Igor да , я пробовал сказал что работает , но я ошибся , дело в том что когда применяю ваш код , он мне даёт true только когда в самом конце ставлю X

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, я не смог осознать ваши проверки. Но, я уверен, они даже близко не рабочие. Я попытался переписать ваше условие, но у меня получилось раз в 5 больше операций сравнения. Десятиэтажная непонятная портянка кода. И я решил переписать в другом ключе.

**Гибкий и простой вариант, не зависящий от количества ячеек**

На свежую голову написал гораздо более простой и лаконичный вариант. Он не зависит от количества ячеек и не требует никакой настройки.

Логика работы базируется на следующем правиле определения победы в игре:

- победная комбинация является или полным набором ячеек одной строки (индекс у строки одинаков, ячейки перебираем от 0 до максимума по очереди)
- или набором ячеек одного столбца (одинаковый индекс столбца, строки перебираем от 0 до максимума)
- или диагональю из верхнего-левого угла в правый нижний (перебираем по очереди все ячейки, стоящие в пересечении одинаковых индексов строк и столбцов: 0х0, 1х1, 2х2, etc)
- или диагональю из левого-нижнего в правый-верхний угол (координаты ячеек можно выразить через `[max - n - 1] x [n]`. То есть, для таблицы 3х3 нужно перебрать ячейки (n - номер итерации) n=0: [3 - 0 - 1]x[0] (2х0), n=1: [3 - 1 - 1]x[1] (1х1), n=2: [3 - 2 - 1]x[2] (0х2)

Рабочий пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/ds08m36y/1/

Пример дополнен инпутом, в котором нужно ввести число, после чего таблица будет перерисована соответствующим количеством строк-столбцов.

Полный js-код из примера (кроме самой функции `proverka` добавлен функционал перерисовки таблицы и навешивания слушателей):

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

function proverka() {

  var flag;
  var count = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var winRow = true,
        winColumn = true,
        winLeftTop = true,
        winLeftBottom = true;

    for(var k = 0; k < count; k++){
      if(table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML !== 'X') winRow = false;
      if(table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML !== 'X') winColumn = false;
      if(table.rows[k].cells[k].innerHTML !== 'X') winLeftTop = false;
      if(table.rows[count-1-k].cells[k].innerHTML !== 'X') winLeftBottom = false;
    }

    if(winRow || winColumn || winLeftTop || winLeftBottom){
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }  

  if (flag) {
    alert("победа");
  }
}

//вешаем слушатели события click на поля таблицы после ее перерисовки
var setTdListeners = function(){
  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
    tds[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(this.innerHTML !== 'X'){
        this.innerHTML = 'X';
      } else {
        this.innerHTML = '';
      }
      proverka();
    })
  };
};

//перерисовка таблицы после потери фокуса полем input
document.getElementById('count').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  var count = this.value;
  table.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var k = 0; k < count; k++){
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);        
    }   
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  setTdListeners();
});
```

**Первый вариант, не масштабируемый.**

Но представленный вариант, по крайней мере в данном виде, сложно масштабируем. Чтобы сделать поле 4х4 придется забивать комбинации руками. Правда, их всего 10, так что это не сложно.

Рабочий пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/ds08m36y/

```
var pos = [
    //перечисление комбинаций выигрыша. массивы из двух элементов указывают позицию ячейки [строка, столбец]
    [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]], //1 строка
    [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]], //2 строка
    [[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]], //3 строка
    [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]], //1 столбец
    [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]], //2 столбец
    [[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]], //3 столбец
    [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]], //лево-верх - право-низ
    [[2,0],[1,1],[0,2]], //лево-низ - право-верх
];
function proverka() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var flag;
    for(var i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){
        var win = true;
        for(var k = 0; k < pos[i].length; k++){
            if(table.rows[pos[i][k][0]].cells[pos[i][k][1]].innerHTML !== 'X') 
                win = false;
        }
        if(win){
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }  

    if (flag) {
      alert("победа");
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись , дело в том что я писал простой икс ноль (3*3) и там я сразу задал варианты (как и вы тут , я сразу в функции сравнивал innerHTML , хотя не суть ) , сейчас же дело обстоит иначе , таблица создаётся на основе вводимого числа в инпут , , скажем если вести 10 получим таблицу 10*10 , так вот , нужно что правила этой игры сохранились и при таком масштабе

Comment: я тут выложил весь код в точности как у меня есть в HTML  , но почему то не распознаёт функцию click2()

https://jsfiddle.net/Tigran_Hovhannisan/asvtf61h/3/#&togetherjs=d20gdp4Du0

Comment: @Тигран добавил новый вариант в ответ. На свежую голову пришел сегодня) По моему - отличный вариант, попробуйте.

Comment: @Тигран посмотрел и поправил ваш вариант на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/asvtf61h/5/ Функции он не видел, полагаю, вследствие каких-то особенностей виртуального движка jsfiddle. Вроде бы, у вас все было верно написано.

Comment: ,, вечером или ночью посмотрю , напишу

Comment: б не знаю в чём проблема , почему не срабатывает мой код , но код рабочий , разобрались с одним знакомым,,,спасибо всем 
https://jsfiddle.net/Tigran_Hovhannisan/asvtf61h/6/#&togetherjs=d20gdp4Du0

Comment: @Тигран да, ваш код работает. Делает много лишних действий, но работает. Проблема на jsfiddle проста, если бы вы посмотрели в исходный код сгенерированного примера - вы бы все поняли. Ваш js-код оборачивается в функцию window.onload. Соответственно, ваши `click1` и `click2` находятся не в глобальной области видимости. Используйте вместо них `window.click1 = function(){...}` и все заработает.

Comment: да вы правы , мы на быструю руку делали (разбирались в чём конкретно суть одной проблемы , решали и переходили на другую ) , пока что не упрощал ,,, а насчёт window.click1 я не знаю в что это,,,, но прочту ,, благодарен Вам